# How to convert value in T-SQL Views

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-view

I have a view `report` with a column `status` along side other columns. Currently `status` contains either 0, 1 or -1. I want it to be 'pass', 'warning' and 'fail' correspondingly. Is there a way I can do it? Thanks

Currently my query looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW Test_Result_Information AS
SELECT  
    r.ResultID, 
    r.TestID, 
    Name, 
    Descrption, 
    ExecutedOn, 
    Expires, 
    r.ResultCode, 
    ResultType, 
    ResultMessage, 
    Vars 
FROM Results AS r, TestResultPool AS p, TemplatedTests AS t 
WHERE r.TestID = p.TestID AND p.TestID = t.TestID AND r.ResultCode = p.ResultCode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
SELECT CASE when status = 0 then 'pass'
when status = 1 then 'warning'
when status = -1 then 'fail'
end as [status]
```

That should do the trick, assuming I got the syntax right.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my syntax.  I should know better.  :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. However it didn't work in my case. Can you take a look at my query above that I just added? Thank you so much.

Comment: Uh, I don't see where you are pulling the "status" in that code.

Comment: oh its the ResultType.... I changed the name so it's easier to understand without the context...

Comment: All you should have to do is change my code where it says "status" to ResultType.  Assuming those 3 values are all that's ever expected, there is no reason that shouldn't work.  You could even just ad that on to the end, if you'd like to see the raw result as well as the resolved CASE statement.

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you!